# IOS 7 - Unable to read/load an image

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am puzzled here.

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"];
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSLog(@"%d", [data length]);
```

what it read: 859 bytes

actual file: 244kb

So I try to see what DID get loaded:

```
    NSString *byteArray  = [data base64Encoding];
```

And decode this b64 to a binary, check it in an image viewer, its 1/4th of the picture. What is also weird is that a few lines later another .png gets imported in the same manner and that .png works fine.

**Resources**:

The image I am trying to load: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiUyS.png

The result of the import: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebgbq.png

The image that does work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSyS2.png

What am I missing?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason that `search.png` should be that large (as evidenced by `UIImagePNGRepresentation` returning <1kb; you know that function is not expected to return the original source bytes, right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few hundred bytes into the PNG file, it starts to embed 200kb of RDF data for no apparent reason (using Photoshop "Save..." instead of "Save for Web...", perhaps?):

```
<?xpacket begin="Ôªø" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.5-c021 79.155772, 2014/01/13-19:44:00        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
...
```

I have no idea if this is related to the described behavior, but it's certainly disconcerting. Assuming this is for UI in an iOS app, I'd start by just re-encoding your image to strip all of this away.

Comment: Looking at 'spunk_logo.png' (the image that does work) - it shows the same xpacket information (`strings spunk_logo.png | grep x`). This should not be a problem. I did however try 'Save as Web' but this resulted in the same xpacket data. I tried something else. Here is my view in photoshop: [LINK](http://imgur.com/nCoTw8v). And here is the result in the iphone simulator: [LINK](http://imgur.com/xhgNwbW). So what happens is: Everything in my .png gets converted to white. That's why the logo did work (because of the outlines) but an image does not. Any clue why my .png becomes completely white?

Comment: Upon posting this thread, the image being completely white made me conclude that it did not load. But it does load, only it shows up as completely white. This is an UIButton in a navigation bar.

Comment: Ah, UIButtons in navigation bars are always tinted. The solution I had to use was `'[button setBackgroundImage:...]'`. I will accept your answer as an answer because it helped me find out what was really going on. Thank you.